# unable to print title when loading many view files in one method in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

In one method when I am calling only one view file than am able to print title as below,

```
$result['title'] = "bhajan songs";
$result['msg'] = $this->W_model->fetchbhajansongs();
$this->load->view('home/viewbhajansongs', $result);
```

But when i am loading some four view files tha am not able to print title. as below lines of code.

```
$result['msg'] = $this->W_model->fetchkawalisongs();
$this->load->view('home/portfolio2');
$this->load->view('home/header');
$result['title'] = "Kawali songs";
$this->load->view('home/viewkawalisongs', $result);
$this->load->view('home/footer');
```

Anything wrong in the calling view files? suggest please.

Comment: Please describe your problem clearly with code of view too.
Also kindly explain when you are not getting the desired result

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways.

**1.** You can pass `$result` in every view loading line as second argument.

But, I like to use another way

**2.**

Before loading any view, load variables so those will be available in every loaded view.

```
$this->load->vars($result);

$this->load->view('header');
$this->load->view('body');
$this->load->view('footer');
```

Can be found in [docs](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/loader.html#CI_Loader::vars).

Comment: to print that title from $result, i  have to write echo in every view file for same title?

Comment: I don't understand. You have to echo value everywhere where you want it to appear. Is that you are asking?

Answer (score 0):

There is best way to load common header footer and all common file and title.

1. Create common method and pass variable with title in data

   function view_render($template_name, $data = array(), $page_script = ''){

   $this->view('includes/header', $data);

   $this->view($template_name, $data);

   $this->view('includes/footer', $data);

   if (!empty($page_script)){

   ```
     $this->view($page_script, $data);
   ```

   }

   }